# Running ADB commands through powershell

Tags: android, shell, powershell, adb

so I'm trying to run some ADB commands through a powershell script.

This is a simple example of what I am trying to do:

```
adb shell "
echo "in adb shell"
su root
echo "you are now root."
ls
cd /data/data
echo "in /data/data"
ls
"
```

I saw in a [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20765134/cant-run-adb-commands-in-bash-script) to add the "" next to shell and at the bottom but that still didn't work for me. I can start the shell and the first ls works. but it just prints the rest of the commands out instead of doing them. The output I am getting looks like:

```
PS C:\Scripts> & .\test.ps1
: not found/sh:
in adb shell
su root
echo you are now root.
ls
cd /data/data
echo in /data/data
MSM8960_lpm.rc
acct
cache
.
.
.
ueventd.qcom.rc 
ueventd.rc 
vendor PS C:\Scripts>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Note: the path to ADB is within the powershell $env:path so the adb commands are working

Comment: Doing some more testing... If a do adb shell "ls; ls" bot commands work. The problem is when I try to get root access. When I do: adb shell "su root; ls" it gets hung up after gaining root. So the prompt gets stuck at #

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get around this by doing:

adb shell "su -c '[cmd]; [cmd]' "

Comment: Awesome! Thank you (: